# System freezes, hard disk reports "LPM support broken, forcing max_power"

Tags: hard-drive, kernel, ubuntu-16.04

A few minutes after starting my laptop running on a battery, usually when launching Firefox, the computer often freezes for a few minutes, while the system indicator shows full hard disk activity. After a few minutes the computer goes back to a normal function. Sometimes it freezes for a second time.

dmesg indicates a problem with the communication with the hard disk,

```
[ 1569.063724] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1569.063728] ata1.00: cmd 60/18:f0:70:ef:1f/00:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq 12288 in
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[ 1569.063730] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
```

the above message appears 30 times

```
[ 1569.063734] ata1: hard resetting link
[ 1569.383531] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 1569.386325] ata1.00: LPM support broken, forcing max_power
[ 1569.386424] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 1569.386427] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 1569.386447] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:09:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 1569.386538] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[ 1569.386782] ata1.00: LPM support broken, forcing max_power
[ 1569.386853] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 1569.386855] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 1569.386875] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:09:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 1569.386964] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[ 1569.387113] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1569.399531] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399533] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399535] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399538] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399540] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399543] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399548] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399550] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399552] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399553] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1569.399570] ata1: EH complete
```

The system is a Lenovo X250 running Ubuntu 16.04

This problem does not occur with Windows, neither when on Ubuntu but on cable power. I therefore suspect it has to do with my hard disk not supporting power management (PM)  - https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57211

The hard disk is fully tested and it hasn't shown any failure, during the last year that the issue occurs,